# File not sending with FormData in Ajax request

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, form-data

I have an ajax request that is sending a file along with some other info. Everything except the file is the correct value, and the file is always null. I can't figure out why.

Here is the input I have included in the form:

`<input type="file" id="file" runat="server"/>`

On button click, it calls this function:

```
function ButtonClick() {
    var file = document.getElementById('file').files[0]; // correctly gets the file

    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('key1', 'val1');
    formData.append('key2', 'val2');
    formData.append('file', file, file.name);

    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) { closeWindow(); },
        timeout: 30000,
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/api/Example/ExampleUrl") %>'
    });
}
```

When I receive the request server-side, I get the following values:

```
var key1= HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["key1"]); // returns "val1"
var key2= HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["key2"]); // returns "val2"
var file= HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["file"]); // returns "null"
```

And when I take a look at `HttpContext.Current.Request.Form`, "file" is not in the request at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file should be accessible via

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["file"]
```